# Area of a curve $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{(y-3)^2}{9}=1$

Tags: calculus

The equation of a curve is $\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{(y-3)^2}{9}=1$

How to calculate the area of the region bounded by the curve?

Comment: Area of an ellipse is $\pi ab$

Comment: Area is $6\pi$.

Comment: How to find $a$ and $b$ in this equation?

Comment: @marwalix Can you show me the steps? Thanks

Comment: f(ellipse)=$(x-h)^2/a^2+(y-k)^2/b^2=1$

Comment: Equation of the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and change of variable $Y=y-3$ to get the canonical form from your equation

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is an equation of an ellipse with radii $2,3$. Now use that the area of an ellipse is $\pi r_1 r_2$

Answer (score 0):

An ellipse centered on $(x_0,y_0)$ with major axis $2a$ and minor axis $2b$ is represented by:
$$\left(\dfrac{x-x_0}{a}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{y-y_0}{b}\right)^2=1$$
And has area $\mathcal{A}=\pi ab$. Thus, your equation corresponds to an ellipse centered on $(0,3)$, with $a=2$ and $b=3$, such that its area is:
$$\mathcal{A}=6\pi$$